# Bash script returns "command not found" when outside the source folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-not-found

under my directory, `/home/lucas/bin` I have the following script `term_multiscreen`:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ sudo cat bin/term_multiscreen                              
#!/bin/bash
# Initializes Nvidia Optimus for multi-screen functionality.

xorg_process=$(ps aux | grep 'Xorg' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
sudo kill -15 $xorg_process
sudo rmmod nvidia
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
# xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$
```

When I `cd ~/bin`, it runs fine with `sudo term_multiscreen`. When I am outside that directory, it returns `command not found`. I also have `/home/lucas/bin` in my `$PATH`. What am I doing wrong?

BTW here are my permissions:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$ ls -la bin/
total 44
drwxr-xr-x  2 lucas lucas 4096 May  6 15:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 71 lucas lucas 4096 May  6 15:43 ..
-rwx--x--x  1 root  root   137 Mar  2 03:26 init_multiscreen
-rw-r--r--  1 lucas lucas    0 Mar  2 03:24 init_optimus~
-rwx--x--x  1 root  root   260 Mar  2 05:54 term_multiscreen
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~$
```

BTW I am on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: `kill -15 $(ps -o pid= -C $prog_name)` - or, if you've got `pgrep` - `kill -15 $(pgrep $prog_name)`. Also, you should probably look at this: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch

Comment: @mikeserv Or use `killall -15 $prog_name`. (`killall` comes with the `psmisc` package.)

Comment: @Lucas Why do you want to call a script via `sudo` that uses `sudo` itself, where necessary?

Comment: @Lucas No, this doesn't answer my question. If you call this script from the shell, the first `sudo` in the script will automatically ask you for your password (or not even that, if you used sudo shortly before). If you always use `sudo <scriptname>`, then the whole script is called in the superuser context and the `sudo` calls within the script are not necessary anymore.

Comment: @Dubu Ah, yes. Good point, calling with `sudo` is unnecessary. Thanks for pointing it out! (I caught this just before you posted, so my other comment was deleted...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest calling your script with its full path: `sudo /home/lucas/bin/term_multiscreen` or `sudo ~/bin/term_multiscreen`. This won't create any security risks connected to `sudo`'s `secure_path`.

Of course that's too long to type (admins are lazy), so put it into an alias in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias tmulti="sudo $HOME/bin/term_multiscreen"
```

Then reload your `~.bashrc` to test:

```
. ~/.bashrc
tmulti
```

If you always call your script with `sudo`, you could also remove the `sudo` calls within the script.

Comment: I think this solution is the cleanest and simplest - and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu?

Define an alias as your regular user: `alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'`.

Or, run `sudo visudo` and change `Defaults secure_path` to `Defaults !secure_path`.
Then, `sudo` will not use the compiled option, `--with-secure-path`.

Comment: It works! So, it looks like `sudo` does not use my `$PATH` by default. Would you suggest adding `alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'` to my `.bashrc`?

Comment: @Lucas Be aware that disabling `secure_path` poses a security risk. If there are or will be any scripts executed via `sudo` (probably without a password), an attacker might be able to execute arbitrary binaries as root.

Comment: @Dubu I did not change the default `secure_path` setting, I only added the alias: `alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH`. Does this alias addition pose a security risk, or were you referring to the `Defaults !secure_path` change?

Comment: @Lucas I was only referring to the `secure_path` setting. The alias is only slightly dangerous as you might inadvertently execute something with an unexpected `$PATH` when using `sudo` under your account. So, someone would have to take over your account to manipulate your `$PATH` to wreak havoc, but if they managed this, they could do more harm in other ways. OTOH, the `secure_path` setting is valid for all accounts, so if someone takes over an account with few privileges which is allowed to start a `sudo` script without password (e.g. a backup account), they could get root access with that.